# Google Sheets Sequential numbering of Column B based on Repeating Numbers in Column A

Tags: google-sheets

| Keys | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 14 | 1 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 12 | 2 |
| 50 | 1 |

Hello all, I'm looking for a way to number sequentially the ID column for every duplicate entry restarting the count for each unique Number in the Key field. Please note that the key field may have a variable number of duplicates (could be dozens or more).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); 
 MMULT((A2:A = TRANSPOSE(A2:A)) * (ROW(A2:A) >= TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))); 
 SIGN(ROW(A2:A))); IFERROR(1/0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

take this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A); 
 MMULT((A2:A = TRANSPOSE(A2:A)) * (ROW(A2:A) >= TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A))); 
 SIGN(ROW(A2:A))); IFERROR(1/0)))
```

[image]