# Google Sheets atomisation

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I hope you are all well and healthy!
I am looking for a solution in Google Sheets to automate something like this:

[image]

and it could auto generate something like this

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome. Did you see this topic on Stackoverflow [Create rows from combination of other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996228/create-rows-from-combination-of-other-rows) in the course of your research?

Comment: How many rows of data do you have? As in the first image on this page... how many rows of switch/location/floor and count?

Answer (score 0):

It is not convenient/efficient for the output to appear in the same columns as the data. You can display the data in adjacent columns, or on a different sheet.

**Name/Location/Floor**
`=transpose(split(arrayformula(textjoin(",",false,iferror(rept(A2:A&"."&B2:B&"."&C2:C&",",$D2:$D)))),","))`

**Port count** (edit the column/row references to refer to the output of the Name/Location/Floor )
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(G1:G), 
 MMULT((G1:G = TRANSPOSE(G1:G)) * (ROW(G1:G) >= TRANSPOSE(ROW(G1:G))), 
 SIGN(ROW(G1:G))), IFERROR(1/0)))`

---

[image: Screenshot]

---

**Props**
 user0:[Google Sheets Sequential numbering of Column B based on Repeating Numbers in Column A](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120411/196152)
 Jeremy Kahan: [Duplicate Rows in Google Spreadsheet based on Value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51577529/1330560)